# How can I solve this issu : /bin/sh: 1: exec: python: not found. Deploying Django app with Passenger

Tags: python, passenger, plesk

I have a VPS with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and
Plesk Obsidian
Version 18.0.58

I'm a begginer in app deployement.

I want to deploy a Django app on this server so I followed this tutorial : https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/12377516625559-How-to-install-Django-applications-in-Plesk-

But I received this error : "/bin/sh: 1: exec: python: not found" and an error page of Passenger.

How can I solve this ?

Thank you for your help !

I tried to find a configuration of Passenger but I didn't find it.

Comment: Do you have Python installed on your computer?

Comment: Yes python is installed, and my app is configured on the server. It’s Phusion Passenger who doesn’t find it.

Comment: Which version of Python is installed?

Answer (score 0):

That error means your system can't find your python executable. First check your python version with `python3 --version`. If not installed yet type `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install python3`.Try to adjust the Passenger Configuration to specify the correct Python exec. path: `/etc/systemd/system/plesk-php73-fpm.service.d/phusion-passenger.conf`. The 73 number must be replaced with your PHP version. Finally restart teh services with `sudo systemctl restart plesk-php73-fpm.service` and `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Hope this can help you :)